# Photographers in Latvia, Riga and Tallinn

Tags: photography, estonia, latvia, lithuania

I am from Germany and I planned to visit Baltic cities (Vilnius, Riga and Tallinn) in the mid of March.

It will be my first visit to those places. As I will be traveling alone in this trip, I planned to have a personal photoshoot in the major attractions.

---

I have looked into the Airbnb experiences, and the personal photo shoot is quite expensive relative to local cost of living, ranging from 75€ to 100€ for a time frame of 90mins. They quote in Airbnb that the photoshoot will be carried out around 7-8 attractions. In real time, is it possible to do it in 90 mins (considering dress changes)?

I checked in google maps, even the traveling by foot takes time for moving from one spot to the other.

Is it quite common to have these range of prices?

---

Where can I find the local photographers in those places, online?

In Germany, we usually look into the local offers in groupon.de

Is there any similar website, where we can dig into much cheaper offers in Lithuania, Latvia and Estonia?

I knew about beta.lt. Are there any sites which are much similar to this?

Comment: Not sure if this is of any help but the YouTube girl I sometimes watch is from Tallinn and is a photographer (possibly amateur). But if you like what she puts on her Instagram I guess you can contact her to arrange a photo shooting. Here's her page - https://instagram.com/lilith__photomake That's definitely one option for you! She should be able to speak in English I believe. But otherwise I'm not sure of a website that would have a list of photographers.

Answer (score 4):

Latvia has several special offer coupon websites and aggregators; to name a few: [Zizu](https://zizu.lv/), [Lieliska Dāvana](https://www.lieliskadavana.lv/), [Gudriem.lv](https://www.gudriem.lv/kuponi/) (an aggregator). You can search “kuponi site:lv” for more, although there’s a good chance the aggregator already shows the same offers. Most of these websites can be viewed in Latvian and Russian but not in English, so I’m afraid you may need to view them through an online translator to make sense of the text. Search “fotosesija” for “photo shoot”.

I have never done such a photo shoot myself, so I am not sure I fully understand what you are looking for. However, I have so far found [only](https://www.lieliskadavana.lv/fotosesija-vecriga-un-tas-apkartne-clover-photo-studio) [a couple](https://www.davanusala.lv/lv/6703-neaizmirstama-fotosesija-vecriga.html) outdoor photo shoot offers in central Riga on these websites (and [one](https://www.lieliskadavana.lv/fotosesija-gleznainaja-sigulda-sanfoto) in Sigulda, a charming town some 50 km from Riga). Most of the other offers seem to be studio shoots. The prices are lower than your quote at €25–€70, but each of them is also advertised to take 1 hour, less time than your 90 minute figure, and no details are given as to what (or how many) attractions will be included in the tour or whether dress changes are included/expected.

I don’t know much about Vilnius, but in Riga and Tallinn, some of the main attractions are located in a relatively small area called the Old Town that used to comprise the actual city centuries ago, and photo shoots seem likely to focus on that area. It is entirely possible to walk straight through the Old Town in much less than an hour, but guided tours tend to take a couple hours. Overall, I’d say it’s plausible to shoot at several main attractions in the Old Town within that time frame. However, if you want to add more outlying locations, you’ll need more time.